# Split the string based on linefeed and map to a limited number of elements

Tags: xslt, split

I have a question.

My input XML looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Text>
    <Message>this is line 1
    this is line 2
    this is line 3
    this is line 4
    this is line 5
    this is line 6
    this is line 7
    ....
    ....n
    </Message>
</Text>
```

The content in Message is separated by linefeed or carriage return and the number of line is indefinite.

The output will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<Text>
  <Line>this is line 1</Line> 
  <Line>this is line 2</Line> 
  <Line>this is line 3</Line> 
  <Line>this is line 4</Line> 
  <Line>this is line 5</Line> 
  <Line>this is line 6</Line> 
  <Line>this is line 7</Line> 
  <Line>this is line 8</Line> 
  <Line>this is line 9</Line> 
  <Line>this is line 10</Line> 
</Text>
```

I have written the following XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:variable name="lineFeed"><xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="carriageReturn"><xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <Text>
           <xsl:if test="Text/Message">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="contains(Text/Message, $lineFeed)">
                        <xsl:call-template name="TextWithLineBreaks">
                            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="Text/Message"/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$lineFeed"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="contains(Text/Message, $carriageReturn)">
                        <xsl:call-template name="TextWithLineBreaks">
                            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="Text/Message"/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$carriageReturn"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <Line>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Text/Message"/>
                        </Line>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                 </xsl:choose>
             </xsl:if>
    </Text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="TextWithLineBreaks">
        <xsl:param name="string"/>
        <xsl:param name="delimiter"/>
        <xsl:variable name="Result">
            <xsl:call-template name="extract-bodytext">
                <xsl:with-param name="GetString" select="$string"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="Separator" select="$delimiter"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$Result"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="extract-bodytext">
        <xsl:param name="GetString"/>
        <xsl:param name="Separator"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($GetString, $Separator)">
                <xsl:variable name="firstline" select="substring-before($GetString, $Separator)"/>
                <xsl:if test="string-length($firstline) > 0">
                    <Line>
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($GetString, $Separator)"/>
                    </Line>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:call-template name="extract-bodytext">
                    <xsl:with-param name="GetString">
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($GetString,$Separator)"/>
                    </xsl:with-param>
                    <xsl:with-param name="Separator" select="$lineFeed"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$GetString"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>             
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now my question is, for the output, I can only map to maximum number of 10 <Line>.  With the above XSL, it will map to whatever number of line exists in the input.

Any suggestions?

Thanks
Ding

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete but short, XSLT 1.0 solution. :)

Comment: +1 Nicely formulated question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This is one way to do it:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <Text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </Text>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()" name="wrapLines">
  <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
  <xsl:param name="pNumLines" select="10"/>

  <xsl:if test=
   "string-length($pText) and $pNumLines > 0">
   <xsl:variable name="vLine" select=
   "substring-before(concat($pText,'&#xA;'), '&#xA;')"/>
   <Line>
    <xsl:value-of select="$vLine"/>
   </Line>

   <xsl:call-template name="wrapLines">
    <xsl:with-param name="pNumLines" select="$pNumLines -1"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="pText" select=
     "substring-after($pText, '&#xA;')"/>
   </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (containing more than 10 lines):

```
<Text>
    <Message>this is line 1
    this is line 2
    this is line 3
    this is line 4
    this is line 5
    this is line 6
    this is line 7
    this is line 8
    this is line 9
    this is line 10
    this is line 11
    </Message>
</Text>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<Text>
   <Line>this is line 1</Line>
   <Line>   this is line 2</Line>
   <Line>   this is line 3</Line>
   <Line>   this is line 4</Line>
   <Line>   this is line 5</Line>
   <Line>   this is line 6</Line>
   <Line>   this is line 7</Line>
   <Line>   this is line 8</Line>
   <Line>   this is line 9</Line>
   <Line>   this is line 10</Line>
</Text>
```

**Solution 2**:

**Using the `str-split-to-words` template/function of FXSL, one can simply write**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
 exclude-result-prefixes="ext"
>
  <xsl:import href="strSplit-to-Words.xsl"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
   <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

   <xsl:param name="pmaxLines" select="10"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
     <Text>
      <xsl:variable name="vwordNodes">
        <xsl:call-template name="str-split-to-words">
          <xsl:with-param name="pStr" select="/"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="pDelimiters"
                          select="'&#10;&#13;'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:apply-templates select=
       "ext:node-set($vwordNodes)/*[not(position() > $pmaxLines)]"/>
     </Text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="word">
      <Line><xsl:value-of select="."/></Line>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the same XML document as above, the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<Text>
   <Line>this is line 1</Line>
   <Line>   this is line 2</Line>
   <Line>   this is line 3</Line>
   <Line>   this is line 4</Line>
   <Line>   this is line 5</Line>
   <Line>   this is line 6</Line>
   <Line>   this is line 7</Line>
   <Line>   this is line 8</Line>
   <Line>   this is line 9</Line>
   <Line>   this is line 10</Line>
</Text>
```

Comment: @Dimitre: Will the first solution work with XSLT1.0?  Let me give it a try.  Thanks

Comment: @Dimitre: It seems working; however, when the first line in the input XML is not in the same line as the Message tag, i.e. it is under the tag, the output shows the first line as <Line/> and up to "this is line 9".  In cases like this, the ideal output will be to have included the "this is line 10" and ignored the first blank.

Comment: @Ding: This is because the line contains NL *before* other text. As a workaround one may use: `normalize-space($pText)` instead of just `$pText` .

Comment: @Dimitre: Thanks again!! I tried it with normalize-space($pText).  The first empty tag no longer exists; however, it still output 9 Lines instead of 10.  The last one was "this is line 9".

Comment: @Ding: Try using: `<xsl:template match="text()[normalize-space()]" name="wrapLines"> ` instead of: `<xsl:template match="text()" name="wrapLines"> `. I think what you describe should never happen if you have `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> ` exactly as in my solution.

Comment: @Dimitre: I tried to change it to [normalize-space()] and it shows the first line as <Line/> and the second line <Line>this is line 1</Line> and the last line is "this is line 9".

Comment: @Ding: It would be best if you post this as a separate question and make me aware (via a comment) that the new question has been posted. I know the solution, but it is not convenient to provide it in a comment. In short, if you want to drop empty lines, then the best approach is to have a two-pass transformation, so that in the first pass all lines are created and in the second pass the empty lines are filtered out and only the first N non-empty lines are returned.

Comment: @Dimitre:  Thanks! If I could not figure out, I will definitely open another question! :)

Comment: @Ding: You wrote _"I can only map to maximum number of 10 `<Line>`."_. Now, if the requeriment change to output exactly 10 lines (including empty ones) you only need to change the recursion condition to `test="$pNumLines"`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using either `position()` or `<xsl:number/>` ?  Either of those may be ways to do what you want to do.

---

`<xsl:number/>` would be stored in a variable and then checked to see how many nodes have been created at that level in the document.  I've used it in an `<xsl:for-each>` loop and presume it could be used in a similar way in this case.

Comment: @JB-King: How would you use `<xsl:number>` here ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd translate() all line endings to a single character so you don't end up calling both $lineFeed and $carriageReturn variants, but just a single $newline call-template. Then create a counter variable set to 10 and decrement it it each time you call the recursive template. test against your original condition OR variable = 0 so will exit whenever you run out of lines or process 10, whichever is smaller.

Answer (score 0):

I modified slightly your XSL and I got the first 10 lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="all">
    <Text>
      unchanged generation of all the lines in the Text list
    </Text>
    </xsl:variable>
    <Text>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$all/Text/Line[position() le 10]"/>
    </Text>
    </xsl:template>

    rest unchanged

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Of course it's a kludge because if you have thousands of lines of which you want only the first ten, then it's a waste...  OTOH, if you know that the number of lines is reasonable, that's cheap.

In addition that would not work in XSLT 1.0/Xpath 1.0 without using a exslt:node-set extension.

Comment: It's XPath 2.0. I've tested with saxon and it _does_ work.  Please note that the OP started the thread in XSL 2.0.